# ContextMenu not popping up on Long click

Tags: android, contextmenu

The context menu is not popping up on the long click on the list items in the list view. I've extended the base adapter and used a view holder to implement the custom list with textviews and an imagebutton.

```
adapter = new MyClickableListAdapter(this, R.layout.timeline, mObjectList);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
       registerForContextMenu(list);
```

Implementation of onCreateContextMenu

```
  @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

  Log.d(TAG, "Entering Context Menu");

   menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");

  menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete")
  .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
 }
```

The XML for listview is here

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

I've been trying this for many days. I think its impossible to register Context-menu for a custom list view like this. Correct me if I am wrong (possibly with sample code).

Now I am thinking of a adding a button to the list item and it displays a menu on clicking it. Is it possible with some other way than using Dialogs?

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why didn't you use `ListActivity`?

In my ListActivity I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* setContentView() and all stuff that happens in this method */
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
    return;
    }

    Something something = (Subway) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(something.getName());
    menu.setHeaderIcon(something.getIcon());
    menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_SHARE, 0, "Do something!");
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
        return false;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DO_SOMETHING:
            /* Do sothing with the id */
            Something something = getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: @Macarse is this for long press?

Answer (score 8):

Such problem arises in list view when it has focusable items like checkbox, radioButton,etc. To solve this in the layout for the list item for the focusable items include :

```
android:focusable="false";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OnItemLongClickListener (via the set~) method of  the ListView.

Comment: I tried using OnItemLongClickListener on the listview. It crashed.

Comment: No. Some other error. I dont remember know. I replaced it with a long click on a text view and displayed a dialog with butttons. It serves the purpose.