# Long press list item to open pop up menu

Tags: android, listview, menu

Hello im trying to make a small menu pop up once an item is long pressed in my list view can some one point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

These posts contain possible solutions to your problem:

- [Long click on list activity item](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/14ba131c3ebc49eb)
- [Show a context menu for long-clicks in an Android ListView](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/)
- [Click & Long-Press Event Listeners in a ListActivity](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/)
- [ContextMenu not popping up on Long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854783/contextmenu-not-popping-up-on-long-click)

I hope it helps.