# how to implement a long click listener and onclicklistener in single listview

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am creating a app in android. In that i am using list view. now i want use both click event and long click event. if is possible can any help me to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955937/long-press-lits-item-to-open-pop-up-menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this

[Click & Long-Press Event Listeners in a ListActivity](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/)

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
        onListItemClick(v,pos,id);
    }
});
```

..

```
 lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
            return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to return true

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> p, View v,final int po, long id) {

        // your code

    return true;
    }    
});
```

It basically tells the system that the Long press event has been handled (default is `false`), and no further events need to be handled (i.e. a single press, which inadvertently would happen in a long press event)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` for a simple click.

For the long click, you have a choice.  If you want to perform a single action use `ListView.setOnLongClickListener`.  If you want a context menu then register the list for a context menu, create the menu and the actions for it.

```
registerForContextMenu(ListView);

    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       // menu code here
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // menu habdling code here
     return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use ListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener) and ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(listener)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: i try it. if i use click event it will work. when i use long click both action will invoked

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setOnItemClickListener()` and `setOnItemLongClickListener()` on your listview.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        }
    });
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following code.

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

Listener definitions will be :

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

itemToclick is the visible portion on which click u want some action

```
itemToClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v)      { 
      //do your logic on click 
     });
itemToClick.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // do your logic for long click and remember to return it 
        return true; }});
```