# How to handle Listview both setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemLongClickListener android

Tags: android, android-listview, event-handling, android-event

i have an issues list view onItemclick and onitemLongclick event handling ,
i have try diffrent way but am not able to fix this issues , i have refred [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview) link.

plz help me.

Comment: Please refer to this [link][1]. I think it will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244491/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-and-onclicklistener-in-single-listview

Comment: event that also i have tyied... stil some time listview onlcik is not working and some time onlongclick is not working

Answer (score 0):

please see this post see this post see this post http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/ it's good example of your needs